# Incorrect state on W-2 withholding

Tags: united-states, state-income-tax, withholding, form-w-2, mistakes

Working on TurboTax, and I notice that my W-2 shows my tax withholding for NC.

I moved twice last year with the same employer as I move to work with their client. But seems my tax withholding didn't change.

First I moved in IL in March, and second and current place is AZ back in September. I don't have a house in NC.

What are my options? And what can I do, also I will owe federal and likely state taxes.

PS: today is filing day.

Comment: Did you tell your payroll department to withhold from either Arizona or Illinois? Also why was North Carolina tax withheld? Did you ever live or work there?

Comment: I remember sending in paper work regarding w4, I think. For state specific tax withholding. I was working in NC till Feb, when I got the call to go to IL.

Comment: Sounds like a fairly complex situation that would be bettered answered by a qualified tax preparer than random internet strangers. You may have to file three state returns. At the very least, you'll need to look up whether those states consider you a resident (for tax purposes) given your short tenure in each place - owning a house there isn't the only criteria, plenty of people rent. Consider filing an extension, which will give you until October 15th, if you can't get this all figured out before the post office closes today.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to check current paystubs and if necessary, adjust your W-4 to properly identified your state of residence. Do not count on your employer to do for you. You probably don't need the state withholding to do your federal taxes, but you may have to file at least in both NC and AZ. You'll have to work out whether you need to file in IL as a part-time resident.